# Get between brackets and word PHP

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to extract a specific value from multiple strings. Lets say i have the following strings:

```
/a-url/{some_hash}/
/user/{user_hash}/
/user-overview/{date_hash}/{user_hash}
```

I want to extract all between curly bracket open and _hash}, how can i achieve this?

The output should be a array:

```
    $array = [
        'some_hash', 
        'user_hash',
        'date_hash',
        'user_hash'
    ];
```

#### Current code:

```
 $matches = [];
        foreach (\Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() as $route) {
            $url = $route->getUri();
            preg_match_all('/({.*?_hash})/', $url, $matches);
        }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should be?

Comment: based on the updated code - you can't override the `$matches` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for that:

```
$s = '/a-url/{some_hash}/
/user/{user_hash}/
/user-overview/{date_hash}/{user_hash}';

preg_match_all('/{(.*?_hash)}/', $s, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

The output will be:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "some_hash"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "user_hash"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "date_hash"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "user_hash"
}
```

Based on your edit you probably want:

```
$all_matches = [];
foreach (\Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() as $route) {
    $url = $route->getUri();
    preg_match_all('/{(.*?_hash)}/', $url, $matches);
    $all_matches = array_merge($all_matches, $matches[1]);
}
var_dump($all_matches);
```

Comment: How does it work with a foreach? Cause if i use your preg_match_all, the $m will be cleared everytime

Comment: If you use a `foreach` loop you can just add each of the values to your array.

Comment: I now have a empty array and i use array_merge on the $results = [];, is that what you meant?

Comment: No, it really isn't. Just use an empty array and add the values from `$m` to that array.

Comment: Ive updated my example, is that what you mean? And btw, the preg_match returns also the brackets and i dont want those. Is there something simple for?